# How do I implement a dial widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement a dial widget in flutter and I need to make a circle RaisedButton to go around center of the parent widget. I can use Center to position a button at the center of the parent container, then transform it. But that makes the button unresponsible. Is it possible to do without using CustomSingleChildLayout? That looks a bit complex

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding your requirement correctly, but a package similar to this called [flutter_radial_menu](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_radial_menu) is available, while the implementation can be seen in this [Git repository](https://github.com/xqwzts/flutter_radial_menu).

The codes are available for your reference, if your goal is similar to this one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Allan. I'm trying to make something like this https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/multitouch-dials.html. The example you gave use CustomMultiChildLayout. I think maybe that's the only way. I'm digging into the code now.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging in flutter_radial_menu, I realized the way to do it is to use **CustomSingleChildLayout**. I need to implement a delegate for it. In the delegates **getPositionForChild** method, we have both the size of the parent and size of the child. We only need to return the position of the child.

I put the code in this gist https://gist.github.com/gliheng/2cc5f97922d456052713fd0803a7efdc